# How to pass html textarea value to a website's textarea after pressing onclick

Tags: javascript, html

How to pass the html textarea value to google translate webpage's textarea?
The replaced word is to be shown on the google translate webpage's textarea to be translated.
There is a 4 languages that can be choose from to translate, but I am not able to do so. After clicking on the translate button, it clears the form and only directs to google translate webpage after 2nd click on the translate button.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="dataSearch()">Find and Replace</button>
    <span id="d"></span><br><br>
    <body onload ="dataSearch()">
    <script>
    function dataSearch(){
                 
        var f = document.getElementById("f").value;               
        var reg = new RegExp(f, "g");        
        var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
        var m = document.getElementById("message").value;
        var count = 0;

        var msg=m.replace(reg,z => {
          count++;
          return r;
        })
        document.getElementById("message").value = msg;
        document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = count;
    }
    </script></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <!--Selection list-->
    <td>Source language:</td><br>
    <td><select name="language">
        <option value="Eng" id="el" selected>English</option>
        <option value="Mal" id="ml" >Malay</option>
    </select></td><br><br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <!--Radio Button-->
    <td>Target language:</td><br/>
    <td><input type="radio" name="targetLang" value="e" id="eng">English
    <input type="radio" name="targetLang" value="c" id="chi">Chinese
    <input type="radio" name="targetLang" value="m" id="mal">Malay
    <input type="radio" name="targetLang" value="j" id="jap">Japanese
    <input type="radio" name="targetLang" value="k" id="kor" checked>Korean
    </td><br><br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="button2" onkeyup="translate(msg)" value="Translate" onclick="location.href='https://translate.google.com'" target="_blank">

    <span id="out1"></span>
    <body onload ="translate()">

    <script>
    function translate(){
      
      var textarea = document.getElementById("message").value;
      var n = document.getElementById("out1").value;
      document.getElementById("out1").value = n;
    }

    </script>


    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetform()"></td><br><br>
    <script>
    function resetform(){
        document.getElementById("p4form").reset();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can't do such a thing as using your own webpage to interact with another one. I think that a valid solution for your problem would be web scraping. Maybe look into a tool like Puppeteer.

Comment: You can. If it is a site on the same domain you can utilize `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. Then you can utilize APIs or dialog instructions within the URL (which works for google) and last but not least you can open a dialog with JSON or databases.